# Where can I ask about getting analytics (statistics) regarding YouTube?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know whether anyone is obtaining usage statistics about YouTube by country. Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).  This is a high level question about using a webapp, but it's still a webapp, and getting YouTube statistics is still using the webapp.

Comment: Wait, just in case, it dont want to get them myself. I want to actually know somebody is gathering them, was that clear in the question?

Comment: @Trufa, I must have made that unclear when I made my edit. I have re-edited. To be fair, you did say "[where] should I ask __how to get usage statistics__ " (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good current SE site for this. If you're going to do it programmatically, you could try Stack Overflow, but if you're just looking for a download page, you might have to resort to Google.

My first thought was Webmasters, but that's for "websites which you control," and somehow I doubt you're operating YouTube. Then I thought about Web Apps, but that's for actually using apps, not gathering metadata about apps. The only other potentially close site was Super User, but Internet-related questions don't usually seem to be welcomed there.

Comment: Thanks! too bad!! and no, you guessed right I´m not operating youtube :) The problem is that I want it for uruguay, we are 3 million in total, so getting a good youtube user stat isnt an easy job