# Where can I ask questions related to YouTube on SE?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am having a problem after uploading a video to YouTube. On which Stack Exchange site should I ask a question about that, if any?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Make sure you check to see if it's already been asked. I know we've had a few questions about uploading to YouTube.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube

Comment: Does this apply to all website-related technical problems? ( Reddit, Quora, Facebook etc..) @ChrisF

Comment: @Pie Yes it does - as long as the question is about how to use the site, not about bugs.

Comment: @ChrisF please take a look at my answer. I posted it because a recent question was closed as a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2023, it depends. YouTube is no longer *just* a website.

If you are using a web browser to access the YouTube website (currently [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)), you aren't mucking around with the developer tools, and it is *not* a troubleshooting question, it's on-topic on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you are having technical issues accessing the YouTube website from a *computer*, it's probably on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) – though please check thoroughly whether your question would be a duplicate.

If you want to publish web video, consider [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): they're best for the technical and editorial aspects of publishing on YouTube. See the [youtube tag](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube).

If you have questions about the YouTube apps for Android or iOS, see [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) respectively.

If you want to programmatically interact with YouTube, you probably want [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), depending on exactly what you're doing and how you're doing it.

Note that there is some overlap between some of these sites: if you have a question that's on-topic on multiple sites, please choose the most appropriate site for the answers you want to get.

## Related

| Question | Recommended Site |
| --- | --- |
| [Where to ask questions regarding the YouTube API?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201996/) | [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) |
| [Where can I ask about getting analytics (statistics) regarding YouTube?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68252/) | [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) |
| [Which SE allows questions about YouTube copyright issues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278463/) | [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) |
| [Which Stack Exchange site is the best place to ask about iPhone's YouTube app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76738/) | [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) |
| [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask about getting information of YouTube's views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370249/) | [Software Recommendations](https://softarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) |

Comment: Regarding [unix.se], IIRC, this site is about using a group operative systems, not about programming as [so]. While both sites might have tags with similar names, their use might not be the same. I swear that I'm not "complicated", what is complicated is Stack Exchange :P I understand and embrace it as it is, not looking to changing / proposing changes in this post.

Comment: Thanks to the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), though, many problems can be solved by running one or two commands, connected to each other. Such questions are on-topic on [unix.se].

Comment: Writing commands in a console is not the same as programming in certain contexts, but that is something to be discussed in another post, I think. Regarding this post, what "worries" me to that some people might get the wrong idea... at the end, askers should review the Tour before asking a question if they haven't done before or don't remember the site scope, or read / take seriously the guidance of the Ask Question page.

Comment: That distinction is why I suggested Stack Overflow; if you can make it clearer, then by all means (what I wrote is a first draft). The tour doesn't tell you much about a site's scope (it's a dozen custom words, max), which is why I linked the `/help/on-topic` pages. But it's your answer, so don't be afraid to fix bits.