# Where can I ask questions regarding the YouTube API?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have questions regarding the YouTube API, but questions on this platform regarding the YouTube API are rarely answered. The YouTube API forums were closed, pointing here for answers.

Where do I get answers? What is the main site for YouTube API related questions?

Comment: "Where do I get answers?" On Stack Overflow, with the Youtube API tag. "What is the main forum for youtube api related questions?" Stack Overflow is ***not*** a forum

Comment: This story does check out. 44.2% unanswered questions in the [youtube-api](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/youtube-api/topusers) tag.

Comment: Please don't [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424788/how-to-use-youtube-api-v3-sample-files-for-net) your [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404145/how-to-use-youtube-api-ver-3-sample-files-of-net) just because you didn't get the answer that you hoped for. Edit the original for clarity instead.

Comment: It's ridiculous that Google is pointing users to SO for questions.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I don't think it's ridiculous, but they *should* probably have developers give answers here, just as they would on their own forums. After all SO has proven that it's superior to forums when it comes to technical Q&A. (Actually, there seems to be [at least one who does](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1973552/ibrahim-ulukaya)).

Comment: The question's premise would make for a discussion related to SE/SO, but the actual question wanders off. How about refocusing it to the SE aspect? [I didn't VTC]

Comment: @AsheeshR: agreed, but *what is* the SE/SO relevant aspect? We can't make people have interest in those technologies.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Bringing attention to *unpopular* tags? While I do not have knowledge of the API, I am pretty sure there would be people on SO who do have the knowledge to be able to answer those questions.

Comment: Can you please point me to the place where they're sending you to Stack Overflow, so I can contact them and get something more informative there? Or email me directly (tpost@stackoverflow.com) and let me know where to find it? Clearly, there's not enough guidance on whatever page that is, and it's resulting in a lot of confusion for users. Sorry about that, they should have at _least_ told you what tags to use.

Comment: @JoachimSauer He didn't realize he was doing anything wrong, actually this explains quite a bit of strange things happening around those tags over the last few days. We have _very specific_ guidance on how to send people to SO for support and if it's not followed pretty closely, this happens. As soon as I figure out where it's happening I'll make this a canonical post.

Comment: @BilltheLizard well, excel tag has 27.3% unanswered all time, and almost 50% last 30 days. does it make it true that last 30 days you had 50% chances to get an answer? No. It depends how much effort you put into your question, if you make it good someone will answer if the question is poor or off-topic chances are smaller. That's why I dont think the %'age should reflect the possibility of getting an answer.

Comment: @mehow "...does it make it true that last 30 days you had 50% chances to get an answer?" Yes, that's exactly what that means. If you start adding more information (like question quality) then of course the probability changes.  I already started working through the /review queue filtering on `youtube` and `youtube-api`.  I'm sure we can improve the % unanswered a little bit from the bottom up, but we need people helping from the top down too.

Comment: @Tim: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/PeW59OgcTZo

Comment: Well, they aren't exactly doing a bad job of sending people this way, although they could be a bit more specific about how to go about it (step 1 step 2, etc). I'll reach out and see if I can help get something more informative in place for folks that might not be familiar with how SO works.

Answer (score 10):

There's been a bit of recent confusion around this topic / tag, I'll try to clear it up.

I've reached out to the group administrators to see if we can get a little more specific in how questions should be asked (including a note to make sure folks apply language tags), there should be some better guidance on the [group closing page](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/PeW59OgcTZo) soon.

For those arriving at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) from the group, here's some things to remember:

1. Make sure you do a search within the `[youtube-api]` tag prior to asking your question. Use the tag as a search modifier because the terms you have are very likely to turn up results from other APIs that you're not interested in. An example search is: `[youtube-api] your keywords here`
2. Don't forget to tag your question `[youtube-api]` *as well as* a tag to indicate the language you're working with (e.g. `[PHP]` `[python]` `[javascript]`)
3. *Watch* your question after you ask it for people seeking clarification in comments, make sure you make edits to your question as needed or answer their follow up questions as soon as you can, so they can give you an answer in the amount of time they're prepared to wait

This should help to make sure that you have a good experience, and (most importantly) get the answer that you need!

Comment: Note that the group closed a year ago - I have _no_ idea where the sudden surge of questions and confusion came from over the last few days. That's the Internet doing its thing, I suppose :)