# Which SE allows questions about YouTube copyright issues?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, copyright

So the audio got muted on a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTpoWPN0Ckc) of mine on YouTube.

> This video previously contained a copyrighted audio track. Due to a claim by a copyright holder, the audio track has been muted.

> #### Your video has been muted.
>
> Copyrighted content was found in your video.
>   Your video is still playable on YouTube. However, because of the claimant's policy, your video has been muted.

The only thing is, the video wasn't some track from a movie soundtrack, it was a recording of me playing a Star Wars Medley as a member of my high school orchestra. I see the button to dispute the claim, but before I do that I need to know, does the fact that I'm the performer of the music change anything (as opposed to the video being just a track from the official soundtrack)? I read up on the subject but nothing I found addressed whether cover songs are permissible and such. Basically, can I dispute the claim on the basis that it's my performance (like a [cover version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_version))?

---

On which SE can I ask this question?

Comment: I personally don't know any SE where that would be on topic, but maybe there is one. On the topic though, Youtube's content protection system is old and outdated, and all that people will tell you is that you will have to deal with it.

Comment: School districts pay ASCAP for these performances, so contact your school and ask about getting a record of that payment.  That covers your butt with youtube.

Answer (score 4):

Copyright questions are well [on-topic in the Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright).

However, do go through their [help-center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help) before posting the question, just to be double sure that you are asking a question which adheres to the scope and quality of the posts in Law SE.

[This search](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcopyright%5D%20youtube) shows all the YouTube related questions under the copyrights tag.

Comment: +1 https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/can-i-record-an-arrangement-of-another-composers-music-and-upload-it-to-youtube from your search looks a lot like the question @RedCaio wants to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at what was [on-topic for Music SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and they say:

> it is not about...
>
> - business or legal issues (some of the latter may be asked on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/))

I suggest that you read about what is [on-topic for Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and decide whether or not to ask there.