# On which Stack Exchange site can I ask about getting information of YouTube's views?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know how I can get the links of all YouTube videos with 100 million + views, so on which Stack Exchange site can I ask such a question?

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask questions related to YouTube on SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110467) You can also check some sites which have a separate (youtube) tag - for example by [searching in the whole network](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Byoutube%5D+is%3Aq) or [using a filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/423567/youtube-main).

Comment: Are you attempting to do this programmatically with the API or via tools available on the web site?

Comment: they just closed my question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159218/youtube-videos-with-100-million-views
q title:"YouTube videos with 100 million + views [closed]"
q:"I want to know how I can get links of all YouTube videos with 100 million + views, so is there any api with information of videos sorted by different things or any other way to get it or even any website that already has it?"

Comment: I notice that you've not taken their tour, nor perhaps read-up in their help centre about how best to approach writing an on-topic question? Usually, the key is to show that you've put some effort into it, show what apps you've already tried, and what was not up to scratch with them. Editing it into shape will bump it into the "Reopen review queue", so that's what to do.

Comment: it's been clearly stated "off-topic" and there is no excuse of "not putting effort"

Comment: My point is, you didn't put in the effort to read the help centre to find out how to write an on-topic question. I'm not a member of that site, but on the ones I'm a curator of, I've voted to open previously off-topic questions after they've been edited to be on-topic. That's all you need to do, read the attendant help centre and edit the question. (As I've previously stated).

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem to be looking for an API, you can ask your question on  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, where API recommendations are [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/903).

Comment: Yeah, Farhang finally got there after getting the direction by someone on webapps and posted a couple of hours ago. Right you should answer and embarrassing that we sent them to the wrong place to begin with.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. embarrassing that the question was closed on webapp instead of being migrated to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Poor user experience.